# Redux Toolkit update state from outside a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How do you update your state using Redux Toolkit if you're not inside a component? This is usually done with `useDispatch()` but I'm not inside a component right now (I'm in an axios interceptor). I tried running

```js
import store from "./redux/store"

store.dispatch(set_access_token(store.getState(), {
    payload: 'mydata'
}))
```

but that didn't work at all. My slice looks like this: (shortened for brevity)

```js
export const auth  = createSlice({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialState: {
        access_token: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        set_access_token: (state, {payload}) => {
            state.access_token = payload
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: "It didnt work at all" doesn't help much, `store.dispatch` should dispatch an action on `Store` instance, depending on how really `store` exported. You should add a reproducible example in a sandbox. https://redux.js.org/api/store

Comment: `store.dispatch` should not be used. You can pass dispatch instance as argument to reducer function and then use it to trigger dispatch.

Comment: @ShravanDhar if you have a suggestion, as such, you should create an answer with a code example.